# Write JEST case for LWC component with nested imperative calls

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am passing the data in `.mockResolvedValue()` method and it is working as expected by providing the correct result.
Example :

```
    getDataFromApex({accountId : this.accountId})
    .then((result) => {
          this.someData = result;
          this.getAnotherDataFromApex();
     })
     .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.books = undefined;
     }); 
 

    getAnotherDataFromApex() {
     getNestedImperativeData({someData : this.someData})
    .then((result) => {
          console.log('getNestedImperativeData result :',result);  //Not getting called from jest
          this.someData = result;
          this.getAnotherDataFromApex();
     })
     .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.books = undefined;
     });
}
```

Have created `Jest.mock()` for both the calls with valid data

Comment: Could you share the code of your tests as well?

Comment: Hey Philippe @POZ 
Thanks for replying back! but got the issue , I was passing the dummy data in the form of object but the method was expecting it in string and doing JSON.parse() to convert the data to object.

Comment: Cool, no problem. Can you close the question then?

Comment: Yes sure thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Got the issue , I was passing the dummy data in the form of object but the method was expecting it in a string and doing JSON.parse() to convert the data to object.
Worked after the right dummy data was sent.